# Why is there a "bubble" in my log graph with no associated commit?

Tags: git

A screenshot should explain the question:

[image: screenshot of git log output]

Notice the "bubble" between the 3rd and 4th commits from the top.  Why is it there?  There is no commit associated with it.  I would think there should be a straight line between 06280ab and 46d4f6e.

#### UPDATE

Based on mah's comment, here's a side by side comparison with the formatting that would make sense to me:

```
$ git --no-p        $ git --no-p
*   3f1c123         *   3f1c123 
|\                  |\
| * 06280ab         | * 06280ab 
* |   7e4d2a        * |   7e4d2a
|\ \                |\|
| |/                | |
| * 46d4f6e         | * 46d4f6e 
| * e77730c         | * e77730c 
|/                  |/
*   4ae17be         *   4ae17be
```

Comment: It is a virtual straight connection. For formatting purposes, the entry isn't straight.

Comment: @mah, see my update above.  I much prefer the formatting on the right, so while you may be correct, why does git graph prefer the formatting on the left, which seems to add cruft with no benefit.

Comment: The problem with the graph you suggest is that the "fork" on the way between `46d4f6e` and `06280ab` looks like a commit whose SHA isn't shown. There is no such ambiguity in the actual graph. If you don't like the graphs produced by `git log`, you should post on the Git mailing list.

Comment: @Jubobs, wouldn't the lack of an `*` next to it make clear that there was no commit?

Comment: @Jonah Yes, I suppose. But keep in mind that yours is a relatively simple example. I'm not sure how well your suggestion would translate to big commit graphs.

Comment: @Jonah I agree with you that the formatting you say makes sense is more useful, understandable, easier on the eyes. That said though, your question really isn't a good fit for stack overflow; you're asking for an opinion, not for help with the tool.

Comment: @mah, well, it appears to have gone that way now :)  At the time I posted, I assumed I was not understanding something about the way git log or git merge works.  Given that I have a decent amount of experience with git, I'd imagine the question could be useful to others too.  Feel free to make your original comment an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a virtual straight connection here but for formatting purposes the entry is not a straight line -- it's just the way the tool designer decided to create the output.

The side-by-side comparison that has been edited into the question accurately reflects the same information in both the actual output format and another possibility. While there are aesthetic differences between them, the information each presents is identical.